# Is it possible to convert an Access database with a not null column constraint to an SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite, ms-access, database-migration

As the title says, I have an Access database, having a not null column constraint and I would like to convert it to an SQLite one. Is it possible for me to do such a thing? And keeping the database in the same state, with it's constraint, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does support the `NOT NULL` constraint so it would be possible for you to convert the Database.

There could even be some conversion utilities.

If memory serves me there was a North Wind conversion. Memory still works so this might be of interest [northwind-SQLite3](https://github.com/jpwhite3/northwind-SQLite3)

Answer (score 0):

You could have binged on *sqlite constraint not null* and would have found as the second hit:

[SQL Data Constraints](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

> A NOT NULL constraint may only be attached to a column definition, not
>   specified as a table constraint. Not surprisingly, a NOT NULL
>   constraint dictates that the associated column may not contain a NULL
>   value. Attempting to set the column value to NULL when inserting a new
>   row or updating an existing one causes a constraint violation.